# JSON Schema syntax for a remote enum

Tags: json, enums, jsonschema

I would like to know what could be the correct way of describing an enum with remote data coming from a web service

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "person": {
     "title": "Gender",
     "type": "string",
     "enum": REMOTE DATA
   }
  }
}
```

Thanks for you help
Xavier

Comment: I don't really get the question. If you generate a JSON with remote data then I would convert the ENUM type into an array when you create the JSON. But I'm not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: I am talking about json schema description : http://json-schema.org/

Comment: Related: [Reference remote enum values in JSON Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63252555/113116)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON-schema just allows you to make references to other schemas locally or remotely via a [JSON Reference through the keyword `$ref`](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor25). It is more or less up to the JSON-schema library how to resolve those references and it does not include a standard mechanism to resolve things against web services.

If you can publish your `enum` data in a public location then you could just reference it as:

```
"$ref": "http://example.com/enumdata#"
```

Or if you want to resolve it within the same document:

```
"$ref": "#/definitions/enumdata"
```

Another pragmatic approach would be to have a preprocessing task to build the JSON-schema. That way you can populate the enum values from remote sources before using it.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it

Comment: Where can I find an example of remote enumdata. Would it look something like this? `{ "myEnumName": [ "a", "b", "c" ]}`

Comment: @Vinni more like `{ "type": "string", "enum": [ "a", "b", "c" ] }`