# Reference remote enum values from json-schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

In my schema definitions, I have a type, with an integer property which should be any of a "fixed" set of numbers. The problem is that this "fixed set" may be changed often.

```
   "person": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "aproperty": {
          "type": "integer",
          "enum": [1, 12, 30 ... , 1000]
        },
      }
    },
```

Is there any way to reference this array from a remote service (which will have the most updated set)?

```
   "person": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "aproperty": {
          "type": "integer",
          "$ref": "http://localhost:8080/fixed_set"
        },
      }
    },
```

I tried $ref, but no luck.
If "ref" is part of the solution, what should de backend return?

```
{
  "enum": [1, 12, 30 ... , 1000]
}
```

or

```
  "enum": [1, 12, 30 ... , 1000]
```

or

```
  [1, 12, 30 ... , 1000]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

main schema:

```
    {
      "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "aproperty": {
          "type": "integer",
          "$ref": "http://localhost:8080/fixed_set"
        },
      }
    }
```

subschema:

```
{
  "$id": "http://localhost:8080/fixed_set",
  "enum": [1, 12, 30 ... , 1000]
}
```

Note that you must be using an evaluator that supports draft2019-09 for the `$ref` to be recognized as a sibling keyword. Otherwise, you need to wrap it in an allOf:

```
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "aproperty": {
          "type": "integer",
          "allOf": [
            { "$ref": "http://localhost:8080/fixed_set" }
          ]
        },
      }
    }
```