# Generating Json schema with dynamic enum values associated with database

Tags: java, json, swagger-ui, jsonschema

I am looking for a way where I can render my react UI using JSON schema and frankly, I am able to solve most of the problems and am currently stuck with just one. I have one object which references an attribute whose values are backed by a database (reference data) not ENUM. Below is one such example.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "animal": {
      "enum": [
        "Cat",
        "Fish"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In the above example, I have an object with an attribute animal that is a dropdown and has fixed values. I can define it as Enum and then it works without any issues. but whenever I need to add a new animal I need to add an enum and release changes which is not an ideal way.

Question: is there a way where the values of these attributes can be backed by either a Rest API which can return a List of values or during Json Schema generation using Swagger we can introspect and then call some method to provide the values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? -- [Reference remote enum values in JSON Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63252555/113116)

Comment: Thanks Helen for commenting. This answers one part of the problem where we can invoke something over rest API. but what about generating the schema with values present and evreytime I generate it update those values.